# Wordpress menus

Tags: php, wordpress

i m having a problem with menus.
I had a template that wasnt originaly for WP. 
so i integrated it.

when i started the site there was only one menu which works great.
i added `<?php wp_nav_menu('primary'); ?>` and its all ok

Now i need to add another one (custom links in the header section)
sooo i used this method

```
register_nav_menus( array( 
    'header' => 'Header menu', 
    'footer' => 'Footer menu' 
  ) );
```

and recieved new locations for menus.
for the second menu i added

`<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu', 'fallback_cb' => false ) ); ?>`

now the problem:
there is a **primary menu** (it has few items)
and the **custom menu** ( its currently empty)

when i add new page to **custom menu** its being shown in both primary and custom menus.

if i delete all the items from **custom menu**, primary menu items are back in place...

what is the problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, it looks like you are pointing to the wrong registered menu in the `wp_nav_menu()`. Specifically in the `theme_location`.

When you are building the "second menu" which is the "footer", `theme_location` should be `footer` since that is the name you gave it in the `register_nav_menus()`.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(
  array( 'theme_location' => 'footer', // Change 'header' to 'footer'
         'menu_class' => 'nav-menu', 
         'fallback_cb' => false )
  );
?>
```

Comment: `<?php wp_nav_menu(
  array( 'theme_location' => 'footer', // Change 'header' to 'footer'
         'menu_class' => 'nav-menu', 
         'fallback_cb' => false )
  );
?>`
these menus i added in addition to a primary menu which was already built it.

Comment: So when you say "second menu" you are referring to `'header' => 'Header menu'`? if that is the case then your code was actually correctly pointing to the second menu. Check in your WP dashboard under "Appearance" -> "Menus" -> "Menu Settings" to see if the "Theme locations" checkbox is properly assigned to the menus you want.

Comment: yes the `'header' => 'Header menu'` is the second one 
i didnt touch footer yet

oh i checked that many times 
primary menu checked as primary 

header checked as "custom menu". 

it seems like custom menu i registered kinda overides the primary menu...

Comment: If you want to have the three menus, you can register another one called something like `'main' => 'Main Menu'` and then make that your primary menu using the checkboxes in the dashboard. See if that keeps them separate.

Comment: wow it worked 
i thought about doing that but i was sure that original menu had to be there. 
well great 
thank you!